# jQuery style getter and setters

Tags: javascript

I have a constructor `Dropdown` which will take an array as a parameter.  This parameter will be used by a method attached to the prototype.  The parameter is an array which should be turned into a parameter of jQuery `option` objects, which should be the drop down menu options for the select element.  Currently I have:

```
function Dropdown(data) {
    this.sel = $('<select>');
}

Dropdown.prototype.options = function (options) {
    var self = this; //using $(this) doesn't work either

    if ( !options ) {
        //if null return the current values of
        return self.sel.html();

    } else {
         //make a jQuery option object out of every item in the array
         //set the sel property's html to that
         self.sel.html = ($.map(options, function (val) {
             return $('<option>').text(val).val(val);
         }));
    }
}

var testArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var dropdown = new Dropdown(testArray);
dropdown.sel.appendTo($('body'));
console.log(dropdown.options()); //nothing outputted to the console
```

by passing testArray into the Dropdown constructor this should set the html property of `sel`, but it doesn't and trying to use the jQuery style getter prints nothing to the console.  dropdown is appended to the page, just with no options.

Comment: The way you have currently written your code, wouldn't you need to pass `testArray` to `options()` method rather than the constructor?

Comment: @MikeBrant that would be the easy (and my only) way to do it, but I would like for testArray to be passed at the time of instantiation TO the options method, which is on the prototype.  If options isn't on the prototype, this isn't an issue, but if it is attached to the prototype I can't pass the array directly into the constructor?

Comment: Right now your constructor does nothing other than to create a select element in jQuery.  You pass in a data parameter and do nothing with it.  You simply need to add `this.options(data)` in the constructor and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, you're not calling the *options* function in the prototype. After calling it, some other bugs showed up.

```
self.sel.html = ($.map(options, function (val) {
     return $('<option>').text(val).val(val);
}));
```

This turns self.sel.html into an array filled with jQuery option elements, which you're doing nothing with.

I changed it a little bit to get it working. See if it works for you. I believe it's easy to understand.

```
function Dropdown(data) {
    this.sel = $('<select>');
    this.options(data);
}

Dropdown.prototype.options = function (options) {
    var sel = this.sel;

    options && options.forEach(function ( val ) {
        $('<option>').val(val).text(val).appendTo(sel);
    });
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b7pvS/

Comment: makes so much sense when you see it >.<

Comment: +1 more complete than my answer as I had only focused on the initial problem of the method not being called in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Right now your constructor does nothing other than to create a select element in jQuery. You pass in the `data` parameter and do nothing with it. You simply need to add `this.options(data);` in the constructor and you should be good to go.

```
function Dropdown(data) {
    this.sel = $('<select>');
    this.options(data);
}
```